# Maven build dependency through pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

For my project, I'm using code from another project found on github. I've included the project as a separate folder in my project. My project uses code from that project, so I want to build that project and include it in my project without really making any changes to that project. So how do I specify in my pom.xml to run the sub-projects pom.xml?

If it helps, here is the repository of the other project that I am using: [Soda Java](https://github.com/socrata/soda-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not planning on changing it, simply download it & build it once using Maven. This will install it into your local repository, and you can simply reference it in your pom without any issue.

If you can find it in an external maven repo somewhere, you wouldn't even have to download & build it.

Only if you're planning on changing it do you need the aggregate project approach.

Comment: Is there a way to tell my pom.xml to build the git project first?

Comment: If you've not changed it, why do you need to build it each time? Build it once, separately, then your build will take the artefact from the repo. If you are going to be changing it so frequently that you need a fresh build each time, use the aggregator Pom approach below.

Answer (score 0):

You create an aggregate project with packaging=pom and a modules element that has one module for the dependency and one module for your project, and you build that.

Comment: Doesn't this require me to change the pom.xml in the git project? Is there no alternative without touching any of the code in the git project?